# YTD Transaction Count, FYTD Transaction Amount, Last FY Transaction Amount formula

Tags: custom-field, formula-field

I have Transaction object which has Amount__c field.Transaction is a child object to Account.
So I have a requirement where I need to create 3 new fields in Account and populate YTD Transaction Count, FYTD Transaction Amount, Last FY Transaction Amount in them.
How to create formula fields for YTD Transaction Count, FYTD Transaction Amount, Last FY Transaction Amount?
Any help in greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One optimum way to accompolish this :
**Apex Trigger+ Apex Batch + RollupSummary Combination:** 
1. Create 3 fields on Transaction object, all three checkboxes (Is current Calendar Year?,Is Last FY?, Is Current FY?)
2. Write a logic in Apex Trigger(before insert) that whenever transaction is done, update a custom checkboxes field as TRUE. 
3. A Tip : You can invoke SOQL query language to get FiscalYearStartMonth by using below code snippet.

```
Select FiscalYearStartMonth From Organization
```

4. Why Apex Batch ? Ans - to make this foolproof solution, Ex- If Fiscal year or Calendar Year changes the value in checkboxes get invalid. So, schedule the batch to run at midnight on 1st Jan every year and 1st day of new fiscal year every year at little over **Midnight**.

5. Finally - you can create 3 roll up summaries on Account level which sum up the details you want like :
YTD Transaction Count = Count of all transactions with **Is current Calendar Year?** as true
FYTD Transaction Amount = Rollup of Amount with **Is Current FY?** as true 
 Last FY Transaction Amount = Rollup of Amount with **Is Last FY?** as true

Since the batch runs at midnight, the values will reflect appropriately till business goes live in morning.